# How to run a function 1000 times and return microtime() of how long it took?

Tags: php

I want to performance test a couple of php functions. What is the easiest approach to repeat code 1000 times and return how long it took all together via microtime()?

Maybe a repeated loop? I came across a very simple code here on SO recently but forgot to favorite it.

Comment: i know without looking the manual page for microtome has many examples

Comment: "a repeated loop" as opposed to a "non repeated loop" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's so difficult about it? Let's modify this example from PHP Manual

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

$times=0;               // This couldn't be tough
while($times<1000)
{
   yourFunction();
   $times++;
}


$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did yourFunction in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `foreach` and [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

```php
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

foreach(range(0, 1000) as $i) {
   yourFunction();
}

echo "Your function runs for " . (microtime(true) - $start) . " seconds";
```